# JPQL, OR only returning result of one condition?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm trying to write a JPQL query which should get a list which match atleast one of two conditions. When I construct the queries sepperatly they work as expected, but putting them together in an 'OR' returns a list which only match one of the conditions. I don't understand why this is.

This is the full query:

```
SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE ((a.ag.proteinPID.uniprot.AC LIKE :genProt) 
OR (a.aid IN(SELECT a2.aid FROM Protein p JOIN p.articleList a2 WHERE p.uniprot.AC LIKE :genProt)))
```

And the sepperate ones:

1)

```
SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.aid IN(SELECT a2.aid FROM Protein p JOIN p.articleList a2 WHERE p.uniprot.AC LIKE :genProt)
```

2)

```
SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.ag.proteinPID.uniprot.AC LIKE :genProt
```

The full expression returns the same result as expression 2).

Comment: `OR` makes exactly what you want: either first condition (with the ID in those proteins.a2), or the second condition, or both.

Comment: Then why does it not return those articles which match condition 1) only 2) when in the full query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try left joining the entities within the full query for the first condition:

```
SELECT a FROM Article a LEFT JOIN a.ag g LEFT JOIN g.proteinPID p LEFT JOIN p.uniport u WHERE ((u.AC LIKE :genProt) 
OR (a.aid IN(SELECT a2.aid FROM Protein p JOIN p.articleList a2 WHERE p.uniprot.AC LIKE :genProt)))
```

Why this works: if do not explicitly left join, I suppose it makes an `INNER JOIN` which automatically will limit the results.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This worked. Now I just need to figure out why it worked. :)

Comment: Well, if do not explicitly left join, I suppose it makes an `INNER JOIN`, which is not what you want.