# JPQL query with left join searching for entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, cuba-platform

Based on following article
[JPQL, OR only returning result of one condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400664/jpql-or-only-returning-result-of-one-condition)
I created the following query

```
Collection<Profile> profiles = dataManager.load(Profile.class).view("profile-view")
        .query("select p from userlifecyclemgmt_Profile p " +
                " left join p.legalEntities f where" + 
                " p.isAvailableForAll = true or :legalEntity MEMBER OF f" ) 
        .parameter("legalEntity", serviceRequest.getHrUser().getLegalEntity())
        .list();
```

The parameter `:legalEntity` is an object of class `LegalEntity`. This query gives me the following error:

```
JpqlSyntaxException: Errors found for input jpql:[select p from userlifecyclemgmt_Profile p  left join p.legalEntities f where p.isAvailableForAll = true or :legalEntity MEMBER OF f]
CommonErrorNode [<unexpected: [@35,120:125='MEMBER',<113>,1:120], resync=:legalEntity MEMBER OF f>]
```

Using the same query slightly modified:

```
Collection<Profile> profiles = dataManager.load(Profile.class).view("profile-view")
        .query("select p from userlifecyclemgmt_Profile p " +
                " left join p.legalEntities f where" +
                " p.isAvailableForAll = true or :legalEntity MEMBER OF p.legalEntities" )
        .parameter("legalEntity", serviceRequest.getHrUser().getLegalEntity())
        .list();
```

has no error, but gives me only the results of the second part of the `OR` statement. I do understand that JPQL creates an `INNER JOIN` query in the background and that that's the reason. However, how do I get the first query to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I implemented a workaround using 2 queries and then merging the results. But that's not really an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the query this way

```
select distinct p 
from userlifecyclemgmt_Profile p left join p.legalEntities f 
where p.isAvailableForAll=true or f=:legalEntity
```

`from userlifecyclemgmt_Profile p left join p.legalEntities f` expression generates `left join` native query which returns plain result `profile-legalEntity`. `f` become alias for single `legalEntity`, can't be used in `member of`, otherwise `p.legalEntities` can.

`select p` returns the same profile multiple (`legalEntities.size()`) times. So you need `distinct`.

Comment: This works great. Well done! If you could give me a bit more explanation to your answer that would be great.